# Generating the N-bonacci numbers

Tags: beginner, haskell, reinventing-the-wheel, fibonacci-sequence

I'm new to Haskell, and this is one of the more interesting programs I've made with it so far. I understand there are already solutions to this problem that use much less code, but to me this one seems fairly intuitive. Are there any ways I can improve this code to be more readable or efficient?

```hs
fib :: Int -> [Integer]
fib n = (n-1) `replicate` 0 !: 1 ++ (+) `zipPoly` repFor tail (fib n) n
(!:) :: [x] -> x -> [x]
[] !: a = [a]
(l:ls) !: a = l : ls !: a
zipPoly :: (x -> x -> x) -> [[x]] -> [x]
zipPoly _ [] = []
zipPoly _ [a] = a
zipPoly f (a:b:c) = zipPoly f $ zipWith f a b : c
repFor :: (x -> x) -> x -> Int -> [x]
repFor _ _ 0 = []
repFor f a n = a : repFor f (f a) (n-1)
main = do
    s <- getLine
    putStrLn "Starting..."
    putStr $ unlines $ map show $ fib (read s :: Int)
```

Explanations of functions:

- `fib n` is a list containing the [`n`-bonacci numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalizations_of_Fibonacci_numbers#Fibonacci_numbers_of_higher_order), starting with `n-1` zeros and then a one.
- `list !: elem` concatenates `elem` to the end of `list`.
- `zipPoly func lists` is equivalent to `zipWith` but with more than two lists.
- `repFor func start amount` is a list of length `amount` where the first element is `start` and every element after it is `func` applied to the element before it  (`[x, f x, f (f x), f (f (f x))...]`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spacing! Separate function definitions with blank lines.

I'd use `a, b, c` for type variables and `x, y, z` for variables.

A `.` looks cleaner than a `$`.

```hs
putStr . unlines . map show . fib $ read s :: Int
```

I would add another pair of parentheses to make the order of application absolutely obvious.

```
(l:ls) !: a = l : (ls !: a)
```

For similar reasons, I prefer the following.

```
fib n = fibBase ++ zipPoly (+) fibTails
    where fibBase = replicate (n-1) 0 ++ [1]
          fibTails = repFor tail (fib n) n
```

I'd use `cs` for the remainder of the list instead of `c`. Perhaps a `where` helps, too.

```
zipPoly f (a:b:cs) = zipPoly f $ c:cs
    where c = zipWith f a b
```

`zipPoly` needs the associativity of `f`, if I'm not mistaken. Perhaps its worth a comment.

Perhaps use a `fold`?

```
zipPoly f [] = []
zipPoly f (xs:xss) = foldl (zipWith f) xs xss
```

Don't reinvent the wheel too much :). Use Hoogle to search for a function using its signature.
For [example](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=%5Bx%5D%20-%3E%20x%20-%3E%20%5Bx%5D), `!:` is `snoc`. Since you only use it once, I'd replace it with a `++`. Similarly, `repFor f x0 n` is `take n . iterate f $ x0`.

Comment: I never knew what `foldl` and `foldr` meant before. Thanks!